# How to query only the date in a timestamp

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

So in my table there are a number and a timestamp row, there are multiple numbers per day

its like:

| number | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 20.02.2021 16:05:00 |
| 7 | 20.02.2021 16:10:00 |
| 20 | 20.02.2021 16:15:00 |
| 5 | 21.02.2021 16:00:00 |

now i want the average of the numbers of the day of 20.02.2021 but i don't know how i should do that with SQLAlchemy

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will fully answer your question, but to get just the date portion of a timestamp you can recast the timestamp as date by:

select your_timestamp_column::date